# Chrome (webkit ?) rotateX makes cursor not changing

Tags: css, google-chrome, rotation, transform

I'm trying to rotate an image using the CSS property "transform".
Here is my code :
http://jsfiddle.net/Ucph5/4/

And here is the part (using jquery) that makes the rotation :

```
$('#rotationX').change(function () {
    var rotationX = $(this).val();
    for (index = 0; index < selectedElements.length; ++index) {
        var selectedElement = $('#' + selectedElements[index]);
        selectedElement.css('transform',
            'rotateX(' + rotationX + 'deg) ' +
            'rotateY(0deg) ' +
            'rotateZ(0deg)');
    }
});
```

The problem is that when I select an image (by clicking on it), then use the "range" input to rotate the actual image, and finally move my mouse back over the image, the cursor should be a "cursor", as stated in my CSS. But it appears that **only half the image shows the "cursor", the other half seem not to be considered as part of the image and displays a mouse in its normal representation.**

This problem does not appear on Firefox (I did not test with Internet Explorer or Safari).

I hope to be clear in my explanation. If you don't understand, I suggest you to click on one of the images, notice that the cursor is visible everywhere over this image, then change the "range" input value, go back over the image, and notice that the cursor appears only on half the image, and not the other.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens ? I tried using the "-webkit-transform" and I still have the problem.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selectable class is in the same z plane that the div that contains it.

When you rotate it, half of it is above the div, and the other half is under the div.
The half that is under the div wont't change the cursor, because it is the div and not the selectable that is under the cursor.

To solve it, make it stay above the parent div (with a translateZ)

```
 selectedElement.css('transform',
            'translateZ(100px) ' +
            'rotateX(' + rotationX + 'deg) ');
```

By the way, you don't need your rotateY(0deg)

[updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/Ucph5/5/)

Comment: Thank you very much !
This solved the problem, and I understand what was happening :)
The rotateY(0deg) will not stay as it is now, I just wanted to simplify and should have removed it for this example :)